# Going crazy cause I can't set up a DKIM

Tags: email, txt, spam, cname, dkim

Hope to find a solution here.

I use lemlist to send automated e-mail, and it requires me to set up a DKIM, DMARC and SPF. My e-mail provider is 1and1.com (Ionos).

I did set up a DMARC and SPF record, but still can't make a DKIM, although I followed every guideline I could find on internet.

To sum it up : I created a public key and added a TXT record with the public key in it. DMARCLY can easily find the key and everything, but every time I refresh the DNS on lemlist, lemlist doesn't detect the DKIM, or should I say, there is no DKIM signature in my mails.

On some resources, I see a CNAME records, and it's not said to do so on the lemlist guideline.

Can anyone help me with that please ?

I tried possibly everything: TXT records, CNAME records, but none seems to work.

Comment: The public key in DNS is used by other mail servers to validate the signature. You still need to use the private key to sign the emails.

Answer (score 3):

IONOS does not offer DKIM for their Basic Mail service. This is a very unsatisfactory situation. I have just been chatting to support who claim that SPF and DMARC is all that is needed - which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

They support it now, noticed this week that my emails started passing DKIM, IONOS added the DNS settings to my domain. Here's where they detail it now:
https://www.ionos.com/help/domains/configuring-mail-servers-and-other-related-records/email-authentication-with-dkim/